# Почему не добавляет скрипт в WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, плагин, wp-plugin

```
    <?php
/*
* Plugin Name: cody_gallery
*/

// Registering styles and scripts
function add_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style',  plugins_url( '/assets/css/style.css' ), __FILE__ );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'my_scripts', plugins_url( '/assets/js/my_js.js' ), __FILE__);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_scripts' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );

// Registering metaboxes
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'metatest_init');
add_action('save_post', 'metatest_save');

// Initializing which metaboxes we need
function metatest_init() {
...
```

Так же пробовал такую запись

```
    /*
* Plugin Name: cody_gallery
*/

// Registering styles and scripts
function add_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style',  plugins_url( '/assets/css/style.css' ) ,false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'my_scripts', plugins_url( '/assets/js/my_js.js' ), 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_scripts' );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

Все - равно не хочет добавлять, ани в админку, или фронт - енд. Я не пойму что не так?

Answer (score 0):

Уберите слеш в начале первого аргумента plugins_url(), дабы было примерно так:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_style',  plugins_url( 'assets/css/style.css' ), __FILE__ );
```